# android: saving some data

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, file

Hi i need you opinion guys. I use files .dat for saving some info. Is it good way?? I know about SQLite but i don't need much info to save, only one word. I mean each file will have a description, and that description i want to save to file.dat .   So should i use .dat or SQLite? Which is better? example of using .dat:

```
    public ImageMetadata(final Context c, final String imageName) {
    dataFile = new File(
            c.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() +
            File.separator +
            imageName +
            ".dat");
```

Comment: you can use shared preferences for that...

Comment: i'll add an example as the answer...please see it..

Comment: @Lal is right. You don't need all the effort required by reading/writing a text file. For managing so little data, **SharedPreferences are... preferrable** ;)

Comment: see my answer for an example.. @Paltroth

Answer (score 2):

**SharedPreferences** can be used for in such situations..

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for more details please..

```
SharedPreferences wmbPreference1,wmbPreference2;    
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

//wmbPreference for Shared Prefs that lasts forever
wmbPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  

//installsp for Shared Prefs that lasts only just once each time program is running
wmbPreference2 =getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MYKEY",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To save values onto the SharedPreference like this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
editor.putString("MYKEY", "stringvalue");
editor.commit();
```

and can retrieve the values like

```
String tag= wmbPreference1.getString("MYKEY", "default_value_to_be_returned");
```

where **MYKEY** is the **keyname** by which you can identify the value..

You can use `putString`,`putBoolean`,`putFloat` etc as per your needs..

Comment: but i have much files which need to have descriptions, for that i can use shared preferences too?

Comment: i use it for adding tags to photos. F

Comment: if you want to store a particular value,for eg if you want to check if your app is activated or not, you can just save a boolean value in shared preference and just retrieve the value and check it whenever needed..

Comment: so that means there will be many number of tags for a single photo,right???I dont think SharedPreference will be the right one in uch a situation...

Comment: yes ofcourse, you can use SharedPreferences if there is just one tag..but then you'll have to have separate sharedpreferences for each photo identified by a unique keyname..

Comment: hmmm... i think my variant was easier.  -.-'  i'm makeing a new gallery based on tags + ratingBar. It's for unversity. So i'm thinking  should i create a sqlite for that or files .dat are OK?

Comment: you can use this too...if this is your use then only one shared preference with a key can be used and check the value in the sharepreference and categorise the images accordingly...i think this is the nice approach...

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences is a good way for you, because you need only one word data:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Check this link, I can help you if you have several questions.